# User in sudoers doesn't have write permissions

Tags: linux, permissions

I added a user tomcat in the sudoers file like this :

```
tomcat ALL=(ALL)        NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Then I noticed a problem. When I type :

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

I can make my changes without any problem. But when I try this I get an error:

```
sudo echo "address host" >> /etc/hosts
-bash: /etc/hosts: Permission denied
```

Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: From the duplicate question: _The problem is that the shell does output redirection, not sudo or echo, so this is being done as your regular user._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fails because current shell is doing the redirection not "echo". Since current user doesn't have permission to write to the file "/etc/hosts" hence " permission denied error".
Do this way:

```
echo "address host" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```